# Using EF Core exclusively for managing stored procedure migrations

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, entity-framework-core, database-migration

I am currently looking at a way to automate the deployment of stored procedure changes as we are running the stored procedure SQL manually on all environments for each release.

The first solution I thought of was using EF Core migrations. Is this the most suitable option or is there a better way?

Some things to consider:

- The database related to this repository I am working on is synced with the main database, so there is basically no database management
- It does not have any models of its own
- The repository is for data analytics and reporting, so it will mostly be read-only
- The only items that will change regularly are the Telerik report files and corresponding stored procedures

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say which database you're using, but if it's any variety of Microsoft SQL Server I find SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio a good solution for maintaining all database objects, including stored procedures. Deployment to as many targets as you want is straightforward, and based on the tool comparing the current db objects to your project objects.
[Visual Studio SSDT](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/features/ssdt/)

Comment: Yeah I'm using SQL Server. Thanks for the tip, I'll check out SSDT.